# Get generated script in MongoDB C# driver

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongodb-csharp-2.0

I am using MongoDB.Driver 2.0.0.
Is there any way to see a generated script from linq to MongoDB?

For example my query is like:

```
IFindFluent<ProductMapping, ProductMapping> findFluent = Collection.Find(
    x => hashValues.Contains(x.UrlHash) && x.ProductTopic == topicId);
```

How would this (or more complex queries) be represented in the MongoDB shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### EDIT

Please see i3arnon's answer for a client-side method using `Render()` that is usually easier.

---

You can use the [integrated mongodb profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#enable-database-profiling-and-set-the-profiling-level) to see what the database has actually received:

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2); // log every request

// show the requests that mongodb has received, along with execution stats:
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

Alternatively, you can step in the source code of the driver and wait for it to actually create the message. That, however, requires compiling the driver from source, AFAIK.

Answer (score 19):

EDIT: As of the 2.0.1 version of the driver the `FindFluent` object returned from `IMongoCollection.Find` has an appropriate `ToString` that includes the filter, but also a projection, sort and so forth (if relevant).

So, for this:

```
var findFluent = collection.
    Find(x => hashValues.Contains(x.UrlHash) && x.ProductTopic == topicId,
        new FindOptions {MaxTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)}).
    Project(x => x.UrlHash).
    Sort(Builders<ProductMapping>.Sort.Descending(x => x.ProductTopic)).
    Skip(6).
    Limit(7);

Console.WriteLine(findFluent);
```

The output would be:

```
find({ "UrlHash" : { "$in" : [4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }, "ProductTopic" : 200 }, { "UrlHash" : 1, "_id" : 0 }).
sort({ "ProductTopic" : -1 }).
skip(6).
limit(7).
maxTime(1000)
```

---

Well, you already know you are doing a find so I assume you want to know what the query looks like.

You can easily do that directly from your code using `IFindFluent.Filter`:

```
BsonDocument filterDocument = findFluent.Filter.Render(
    collection.DocumentSerializer,
    collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry);

Console.WriteLine(filterDocument);
```

The output in your case (depends on `hashValues` and `topicId` of course):

```
{ "UrlHash" : { "$in" : [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] }, "ProductTopic" : 200 }
```