# Is there a way in hotChocolate to log the query which is performed on IQueryable

Tags: mongodb, graphql, hotchocolate

we use HotChocolate with MongoDB. I tried the ConsoleQueryLogger es explained in the documentation to log the graphql query. What I want now is to get also the query that is performed on a collection.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to configure it on the MongoClient
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45507691/7188852