# catch mongo requests from app server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mongodb, iis, wireshark, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MVC .net application, running on IIS, that uses mongo.
The mongo servers are sharded, and not in my control.
I want to see the request that my application server sends to mongo (the queries in the mongo syntax).

I tries fiddler, but I saw that the communication to mongo is through TCP, so I tried wireshark. In wireshark I see the request, but is how do I see the full request?

Thanks for the help!

Edit: The answer that was suggested does not answer what I wanted.
I want to see from the application server the requests. It will help me follow what happens in certain situations. Also because we work with 4 mongo servers I don't know with will handle each request.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get generated script in MongoDB C# driver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30306193/get-generated-script-in-mongodb-c-sharp-driver)

Comment: It is not exactly what I wante, see my edit.

Comment: What do you mean, the full request? Wireshark will capture absolutely everything, so the full request is there.

Comment: Its broken to tcp request. When i try to follow the stream I can see little parts of the request and the response, but the full part, and it is filled with jibrish.