# Mongo c# driver 2.0 - Is there a way to print the FilterDefinition

Tags: c#, mongodb

For debugging purposes, I need to print the FilterDefinition as readable string. I have already tried .ToString() which is not helpful as it prints the Type information.

It will be good if I can even print some representation of it which is readable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the Render method of the filter:
http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_FilterDefinition_1_Render.htm

```
var query = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("a", "b");

var documentSerializer = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry.GetSerializer<BsonDocument>();

var renderedFilter = query.Render(documentSerializer, BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry);
```

Comment: This is a mere copy of the second part of i3arnon's answer to the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/30307994/257786

Comment: It isnt a mere copy. I just tested it in Visual Studio and posted my code.

Comment: OK, it still doesn't add much value for a reader I believe, but maybe a downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: @mnemosyn this is much better than http://stackoverflow.com/a/30307994/257786 as this does not require a reference to a collection (which was exactly what I was looking for).